# Сортировка списка

Tags: c#

Класс точка

```
public class Point
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public int distanse()
    {
        return this.X * this.X + this.Y * this.Y;
    }
}
```

и список точек

```
List<Point> points;
```

Как сортировать points по distanse?

Comment: `distance()` в даном случае - квадрат растояния.

Comment: Я думаю, он использует distanse только для сравнения, чтобы не "тратиться" на извлечение корня

Comment: да, это только для сортировки

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Твой класс должен реализовывать интерфейс IComparable, то есть:

```
public class Point : IComparable<Point>
{    
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public int distanse()
    {
        return this.X * this.X + this.Y * this.Y;
    }

    // Реализация интерфейса
    public int CompareTo(Point p)
    {
        return this.distanse() - p.distance();
    }    
}
```

Если сортировка в коде используется единожды, можно воспользоваться анонимным делегатом, без модифицирования класса:

```
List <Point> points = new List <Point>();
points.Sort( delegate(Point p1, Point p2){ return p1.distanse() - p2.distanse(); } );
```

[Подробнее читай в MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.icomparable.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Используя LINQ (не меняя класс):

```
List<Point> sorted = points.OrderBy(p => p.distanse()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Если не хочешь менять свой класс, тожно cделать так:

```
public class PointComparer : IComparer<Point> {
    public int Compare(Point a, Point b) {
        return a.distanse() - b.distanse();
    }
}
```

а сортировать так:

```
points.Sort(new PointComparer());
```

Comment: Правильнее сказать, что данный подход следует использовать, когда класс к разработчику пришел извне, например, в составе DLL, и целевой класс недоступен для редактирования. Но, если сортировка в коде используется единожды, можно поступить так: 
List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
points.Sort(delegate(Point p1, Point p2){
                  return p1.distanse() - p2.distanse();
              });

Answer (score 2):

Еще вариант, не требующий изменения класса:

```
points.Sort((a, b) => a.distance() - b.distance());
```

Comment: Это другая форма записи ответа deSharp'a для анонимного делегата.